# Select attribute name of an element

Tags: xml, xpath

This is a sample XML:

```
<parentNode name="Any Name">

    <childNode>50</childNode>

</parentNode>
```

I want to check, if content of 'childNode' is '50' then display the name 'Any Name' with the help of XPath. Please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: "display the name 'Any Name'"? Are you using XSLT to transform this XML?

Comment: No. I am just writing a query.

Comment: Just to extract the name if childNode=50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the path `/parentNode[childNode = 50]/@name` selects the attribute called `name` if the element called `childNode` is 50.